# Interfacing zigbee usb stick module with MSP430(Fingerprint Development Kit Texas instruments C5515)

Tags: zigbee, interfacing

I am developing a wireless finger print based attendance management system to be deployed in my university(National university of sciences and technology Pakistan). I want to use "ETRX357USB+8M ZigBee Wireless Mesh Networking USB Stick" in my project.

**Question**:
how can i interface MSP430 controller of c5515 finger development kit with ETRX357USB zigbee in order to transmit the data to my server ?

There is a USB port on the finger developing kit(FDK) i am using (Texas instruments C5515) so i have query whether it can host the USB stick Zigbee or not, as hosting a USB device requires driver to be installed on the hosting machine(in my case C5515).

Answer (score 1):

The Telegesis USB sticks all use a Silicon Laboratories Serial-to-USB chip.  When you connect them to a PC (or Mac/Linux), you have to install the [drivers](http://www.telegesis.com/telegesis_zigbee_technology_-_technical_support_/software_download.htm) and the device will show up as a COM port.  If the MSP430 is running Linux, you may be in luck, but otherwise I don't know that this product will fit your use case.

You might look at their [Zigbee Module](http://www.telegesis.com/product_range_overview/etrx3_zigbee_module.htm) which would provide you with UART access, or perhaps one of the [Digi XBee](http://www.digi.com/xbee/) devices.